# Invariant measure nomenclature

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I'm looking through my notes and I've come across the following line:

> If $\sum_{i \in I}\pi(i) = \infty$ then we (usually) say that the Markov chain doesn't have an invariant distribution.

My problem is with the "(usually)" part of this sentence. For a probability distribution we require that the $\sum_{i \in I}\pi(i) = 1$ so this "(usually)" seems rather misleading.

Can I get confirmation that I copied this down in error?

Answer (score 0):

An invariant **measure** for a Markov chain satisfies

\begin{equation}
\pi P = \pi,
\end{equation}

where $\pi = [ \pi_x ]_{x \in I}$ is a row vector and $P = [p_{x,y}]_{x,y \in I}$ is the transition probability matrix.

If the Markov chain is irreducible, positive recurrent, and aperiodic, then $\pi$ is unique up to scalar multiples. This means that you can normalize the vector $\pi$ so that it sums to $1$. So, an invariant **distribution** satisfies

\begin{equation}
\pi P = \pi, \quad \pi \mathbf{1} = 1
\end{equation}

with $\mathbf{1}$ a column vector of ones of appropriate size. If the invariant measure has $\pi \mathbf{1} = \infty$, then you cannot normalize it to obtain an invariant distribution.

Comment: You've just given the definition, which isn't what I'm having problems with. I'm specifically questioning why there is the word "(usually)" in the sentence.