# Normalisation of an invariant measure

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, invariant-theory

Is there an example of a Markov chain with invariant measure $\pi$ and $\sum_{i \in I}\pi(i) = \infty$ that can be normalised so that we can consider an invariant distribution instead?

This is a thought in relation to my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1690792/invariant-measure-nomenclature).

Comment: What about infinite Markov chain, where each state is absorbing? Every measure is invariant for it, and hence there will be $\pi$ which sums up to infinity, but there will also be some other invariant measure with a finite sum.

Comment: @Ilya Could you elaborate on this? The transitional probability matrix will not have finite dimension and I'm not sure how to work with matrices in such a case. How would you find $\pi$ and why would there be some other invariant measure with a finite sum?

Comment: I think your question suggests some misunderstanding. If you have an invariant measure $\pi_0$ of infinite total measure, then it can't be normalized into an invariant distribution. That is, the existence of this particular $\pi_0$ does not imply that there is an invariant distribution. However, in principle there could still be another invariant measure $\pi_1$ that can be normalized into an invariant distribution. This is where the meaningful question arises.

Comment: Ilya's example was $P$ is the identity matrix. Then every measure is an invariant measure; and so you can take one then somehow do a weird normalization. The "right question" is to ask for an *irreducible* Markov chain with this property. Then the answer is no. The issue is that infinite invariant measures arise for null recurrent Markov chains; whereas finite invariant merasure arise for positive recurrent Markov chains.

Comment: @Ian Yes, that is what I initially thought too. What seems to have happened is that I didn't restrict the types of Markov chains that I wanted to look at. I realised this after reading anthonyquas's comment, since my question only makes sense if the invariant measure is unique. Thanks for the comments all, they helped a lot. Perhaps an answer can be formulated from these comments to close it up?